# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied. ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

So the problem is the following:

When i click the submit button on my register web form (after adding the corresponding values in the textboxes) there is an error on the line "`oCom.ExecuteNonQuery();`". It says

> "Procedure or function 'ADDUSR' expects parameter '@useremail', which
>   was not supplied."

And I keep trying to find out why it says that because I double checked and `oUsr.Email = "hello@hello.com"`, that info comes from the debugger and it makes sense because I just added it on the textbox before clicking the submit button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Carnisoftix
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carniuser oUsr = new carniuser();

            oUsr.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            oUsr.Name = txtName.Text;
            oUsr.Pass = txtPassword.Text;
            oUsr.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
            oUsr.Usrname = txtUsername.Text;
            oUsr.Address = txtAddress.Text;
            oUsr.SpecialK = Convert.ToInt16(txtSpecial.Text);
            oUsr.Auth = 1;
            regUsr(oUsr);

        }
        public static void regUsr(carniuser oUsr)
        {
            //int oNum;
            SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=L:\\Apps\\VS Projects\\Carnisoftix\\CarniDb.mdf;Database=CarniDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
            string oSql = "ADDUSR";
            SqlCommand oCom = new SqlCommand(oSql, oConnection);
            oCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail ,", oUsr.Email);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass, ", oUsr.Pass);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name, ", oUsr.Name);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone, ", oUsr.Phone);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address, ", oUsr.Address);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username, ", oUsr.Usrname);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authority, ", oUsr.Auth);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special, ", oUsr.SpecialK);
            //SqlParameter oReturn = new SqlParameter("@out", SqlDbType.Int);
            //oReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            //oCom.Parameters.Add(oReturn);
            oConnection.Open();
            oCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //oNum = (int)oCom.Parameters["@out"].Value;
            oConnection.Close();
            //return oNum;
        }
    }
    /* my database's stored procedure requires this parameters:
    @useremail,
    @username,
    @userpass,
    @name,
    @phone,
    @address,
    @authority,
    @special*/
    public class carniuser
    {
        private string email, usrname, pass, name, phone, address;
        private int authority, specialK;
        public carniuser()
        {
            email = "";
            usrname = "";
            pass = "";
            name = "";
            phone = "";
            address = "";
            authority = 1;
            specialK = 1;
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        public string Pass
        {
            get { return pass; }
            set { pass = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }
        public string Usrname
        {
            get { return usrname; }
            set { usrname = value; }
        }
        public int Auth
        {
            get { return authority; }
            set { authority = value; }
        }
        public int SpecialK
        {
            get { return specialK; }
            set { specialK = value; }
        }

        public carniuser(string email, string usrname, string pass, string name, string phone, string address, int authority, int specialK)
        {
            Email = email;
            Usrname = usrname;
            Pass = pass;
            Name = name;
            Phone = phone;
            Address = address;
            Auth = authority;
            SpecialK = specialK;
        }
    }
}
```

And here you have the database's stored procedure that im trying to use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDUSR

@useremail varchar (35),
@username varchar (30),
@userpass varchar (30),
@name varchar (100),
@phone varchar (20),
@address varchar (150),
@authority int,
@special bit

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO USERS
(
_UserEmail,
_UserName,
_UserPass ,
_Name ,
_Phone,
_Address,
_Authority,
_Special
)
VALUES
(
@useremail,
@username,
@userpass,
@name,
@phone,
@address,
@authority,
@special
)
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made a mistake when you wrote `usermail` parameter.

Change

```
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail ,", oUsr.Email);
```

to

```
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", oUsr.Email);
```

And delete all your comma's in your `AddWithValue` methods. Like;

```
oCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", oUsr.Email);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass", oUsr.Pass);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", oUsr.Name);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", oUsr.Phone);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", oUsr.Address);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", oUsr.Usrname);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authority", oUsr.Auth);
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", oUsr.SpecialK);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail ,", oUsr.Email);
                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: To add to this answer, look into all your `AddWithValue` calls, they all have commas with them, which is not right.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
static string connectionString = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=L:\\Apps\\VS Projects\\Carnisoftix\\CarniDb.mdf;Database=CarniDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

public static void regUsr(carniuser oUsr)
{
    using(SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        oConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand oCom = new SqlCommand("ADDUSR", oConnection))
        {
            oCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", oUsr.Email);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass", oUsr.Pass);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", oUsr.Name);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", oUsr.Phone);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", oUsr.Address);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", oUsr.Usrname);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authority", oUsr.Auth);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", oUsr.SpecialK);
            oCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        oConnection.Close();
    }
}
```